# How to add the previous list item value with the current listitem value in android

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I am creating an application in which i have a list view which takes the data from sq lite database everything works fine but what i have to do is sum the previous list item value with the current items value and show that value in the current item like this i have to show the entire list.
   In the picture which i have given below has the column named advance as well as balance in which the balance column will get the advance column values.so that advance column values gets added and it should be displayed in the balance column.

[image]

I would like to know is it possible to do like this.

Comment: if you are using activities for both listviews you can send values to 2nd activity by using intent in setonitemclicklistener

Comment: no i am doing it in a single activity

Comment: What specific data do you get from the database?

Comment: @jordi Sipkens i am getting all the data's from the table.What i want to do is similar like fibonacci series taking the advance amount and adding the advance amount and show it in the balance

Comment: just add the balance value to your class/model and calculate it with your previous object and current object. If that is what you mean.